# I can’t get the correct answer when parsing the site

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to parse the site - https://www.rent-a-car-crete.gr/car-search/
in order to get the necessary information, the parser must enter the following data

```
 data = {
    'pickup_location': '29',
'return_to_pickup_location': '1',
'return_location': '---',
'pickup': '21.02.2024',
'pickup_time': '10:00',
'return': '22.02.2024',
'return_time': '10:00',
'promo_code': '',
'age': '30+',
'pickup_id': '',
'return_id': '',
'subimt_search': '1',
    }
```

(looked at the full list in the network)
and how to press the search button and parse the cars that come out

I tried to parse the main page - https://www.rent-a-car-crete.gr
[image]
without a post request I received it, when sending a post request I also received it, I was not transferred to the page with the car, after looking at what I get when parsing the main page and the page described above, I realized that I get the same text everywhere, I can’t understand how I can achieve the result I need. Here are screenshots that can help and my code
[[image]]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahv3c.png)
[image]

```
url = 'https://www.rent-a-car-crete.gr/car-search/'
urlpre = 'https://www.rent-a-car-crete.gr'

work =  Session()

res = work.post(url=url, headers=headers,data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
cars = soup.find_all('h3', class_='carname')
print(res)
print('-'*50)
print(soup)
print('-'*50)
print(cars)
```

Answer (score 2):

The URL where you POST search parameters is little bit different (you should see it in Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://www.rent-a-car-crete.gr/CarRental/load.php"
params = {"controller": "GzFront", "action": "getCars", "local": "3"}

data = {
    "local": "3",
    "pickup_location": "29",
    "return_to_pickup_location": "1",
    "return_location": "---",
    "pickup": "22.02.2024",
    "pickup_time": "10:00",
    "return": "23.02.2024",
    "return_time": "10:00",
    "promo_code": "",
    "age": "30+",
    "continue": "Select",
    "pickup_id": "",
    "return_id": "",
    "subimt_search": "1",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.post(api_url, params=params, data=data).content, "html.parser"
)

for h3 in soup.select("h3.carname"):
    print(f'{h3.text:<60} {h3.find_next(class_="price").text.strip()}')
```

Prints:

```
Toyota Aygo or similar                                       € 79 
Peugeot 108 or similar                                       € 79 
Suzuki Alto or similar                                       € 79 
Volkswagen Up! or similar                                    € 79 
Skoda Citigo Aut or similar                                  € 93 
Fiat 500 Hybrid                                              € 86 
Fiat Panda or similar                                        € 80 

...
```

Comment: where did you find this parametrs and "local" in data, i have not seen it in network tab
and wy do you use another url - www.rent-a-car-crete.gr/CarRental/load.php